# Refactoring method that is mostly the same except for one line

Tags: c++, refactoring

Note:  Edited test to be x==1

```
if(x==1) {
  statement1();
  statement2();
  special1();
  statement3();
  statement4();
else {
  statement1();
  statement2();
  special2();
  statement3();
  statement4();
}
```

What is the right way to factor this down as much as possible.  I was thinking making an abstract base class (with a method that does statments 1-4) that implements a pure virtual special method (that either does special1 or 2) - and have subclasses implement that method.  The if else would result in.

```
 Checker myChecker = (x==1) ? Specal1Checker() : Special2Checker();
 myChecker.doCheck();
```

Comment: Are you using java or c++?

Comment: Why not `stmt1(); stmt2(); if (x==1) { special1(); } else { special2(); } stmt3(); stmt4();`?

Comment: The right thing would be to remove everything from the else on down (and the if preamble), since in C++ `x=1` is **always** true.

Comment: Is the assignment `x=1` intentional or a bug.

Comment: x==1: edited the question

Comment: Removed java from tags

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x=1` is a typo and it should be `x==1`, here's what to do in C++:

```
bool const descriptive_name = (x == 1);
statement1();
statement2();
if( descriptive_name ) { special1(); } else { special2(); }
statement3();
statement4();
```

Expressing this also in Java is left as an exercise.

---

At the time of posting the original code to be refactored was

```
if(x=1) {
  statement1();
  statement2();
  special1();
  statement3();
  statement4();
else {
  statement1();
  statement2();
  special2();
  statement3();
  statement4();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to store the condition in a local variable?

Comment: @NeilKirk: because the value of `x` can be changed by `statement1()` or `statement2()`, assuming that they're not just function calls.